# Интеграция Apache2 и Tomcat 9

Tags: java, apache, servlet, tomcat, apache2

Установил Apache, Tomcat и mod_jk. Часть worker.properties:

```
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
```

Apache слушает порт 80. Часть jk.conf:

```
JkMount /tui/* ajp13_worker
JkMount /tui ajp13_worker
```

Tomcat слушает 8009. Часть server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Приложение находится в `/opt/tomcat/webapps/tui/`. В нем есть index.html и сервлет. С сервлетом все в порядке он обрабатывается и доступен через `localhost:8080/tui/servlet`. Также index.html открывается через `localhost:8080/tui`. Однако, это прямое обращение к Tomcat (ведь так?). Если попытаться обратиться через порт 80, то Apache ссылается не туда куда надо. Т.е., вероятно, Apache не коннектится с Tomcat. Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы заставить Apache обрабатывать статику, а tomcat сервлеты и JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема была не одна:

**Во-первых**, в `worker.properties` установить `workers.java_home` и `workers.tomcat_home` в значения не по-умолчанию.

**Во-вторых**, прописывать `JkMount` нужно было в директиве `<VirtualHost>`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tui
    DocumentRoot /opt/tomcat/webapps

    <Directory /opt/tomcat/webapps>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    JkMount /tui/servlet* ajp13_worker
</VirtualHost>
```

**В-третьих**, как видно выше (`Require all granted`), нужно было дать возможность обращения к директории с приложением (сайтом), так как по умолчанию Apache запрещает обращаться ко всему, что лежит вне `/usr/share` и `/var/www`

**В-четвертых**, (теоретически не обязательно), я писал `<VirtualHost>` не в jk.conf, а в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

P.S. Если выполнять пункт 4, то нужно добавить в `/etc/hosts` следующее:

```
127.0.0.1 tui
```